# Adding a JNI library to the local Maven Repository

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, maven-nar-plugin

I wish to add a JNI library, including its shared object (.so) file to my project using Maven. Unfortunately it is not yet on a public repository so I guess I have to install it myself on my local repository to have it working.

How do I go about including the native part in Maven to be bundled in my project (and eventually exported with the copy-dependencies plugin). This is a standard J2SE app (not a web-app), with packaging .jar?

The library I am trying to add is [junixsocket](http://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/), just in case it helps to know.
It has a .so (native library) component, and the Java .jar component.

I came across [maven-nar-plugin](http://duns.github.com/maven-nar-plugin/index.html) which seems to target native builds, but seems to be more oriented towards building a JNI project from code, rather than bundling a 3rd party JNI library, and I can't get to piece the jigsaw puzzle together.

How do I go about:

1. Installing these in my local repository, having the .jar depending on the .so library.
2. Including the dependency (on the .jar and .so) in the POM file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

My approach:

Put `.so` files to repository with platform specific classifier, like this: `sqlite3-3.7.9-linux-x86_64.so`.
 Add `.so` dependencies for all required platforms:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.ch-werner</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.9</version>
    <type>so</type>
    <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Use this maven assembly plugin config to put all native libs into `lib/native` directory of you dist:

```
<dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>lib/native</outputDirectory>
    <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
    <unpack>false</unpack>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <useStrictFiltering>false</useStrictFiltering>
    <includes>
        <include>*:*:dll:*</include>
        <include>*:*:so:*</include>
        <include>*:*:jnilib:*</include>
    </includes>
</dependencySet>
```

Use [this class](https://github.com/alx3apps/ctz-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/concerteza/util/jni/CtzJniUtils.java) to load libs on app startup (planning to change classifier naming to [GNU triplets](http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Tuples)):

```
CtzJniUtils.loadJniLibsFromStandardPath(Launcher.class, "sqlite3")
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the .so with the platform specific classifier with the normal mvn install command?

Comment: @jbx Maybe you mean `mvn deploy`? I used it only for java deps built by maven itself. Our JNI deps are built without maven, and loaded to maven repository with cURL by simple bash script.

Comment: No I meant mvn install. I usually do this for 3rd party libraries which are not in the maven repository. http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html So essentially what I wish to do is include the .so with the 3rd party jar.

Answer (score 5):

I include the .so in the jar and extra the platform specific shared library before loading it. This way it is deployed just like any other jar.

An example of a project where this is done, with multiple .so for different platforms is 
https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity

The main class to look at is https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity/blob/master/src/main/java/com/higherfrequencytrading/affinity/impl/NativeAffinity.java

Comment: How do you deploy it then and make sure that the native library is put in the right LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: It doesn't, it loads into a sub directory of `java.io.tmpdir` and loads it with a full path name.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to unpacking your libraries at runtime, you could store them as jars in Maven but unpack them at build time: http://www.buildanddeploy.com/node/17.

The [maven-nativedependencies-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/mavennatives/) plugin will do this for you automatically, as long as you follow their naming convention.