# Adding A 3rd Party JNI Library to Nexus

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, nexus

I am currently using a 3rd party java library, "foo", that has jni dependencies.  The jni dependency also utilizes softlinks.  The directory structure looks something like

```
foo/
   /foo.jar
   /libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.1.0
   /libfoo.so.1.0
```

**How do I package the .jar & .so, with softlink, and upload to my local nexus "3rd party" repository?**

[There is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071058/adding-a-jni-library-to-the-local-maven-repository) but unfortunately that questioner is asking how to deploy their own project which they can control & manipulate.  In my case I'm working with a .jar and .so that I can't change.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should separate the java library and the native library when deploying on Nexus.

In order to deploy the native library, you can find an idea at the following URL: [maven-bundling-and-unpacking-native-libraries](https://myshittycode.com/2015/11/09/maven-bundling-and-unpacking-native-libraries/)